# Do applications assigned via GPO automatically re-install if they are manually uninstalled?

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy

Questions:

1. Do applications assigned via a group policy object automatically re-install if they are manually uninstalled?
2. Is this intended behaviour (E.g. "just how GPOs work") or a bug?
3. If they don't re-install, how can you get the software to re-install via GPO? Is there a reg key that needs to be edited/deleted, etc?

Scenario: 
- GPO deployed which does an assigned install of an application. 
- User logs onto target machine from the target OU. 
- Software installs automatically as intended.
- User then manually uninstalls the software. 
- However after multiple reboots and gpupdate/force, the software fails to be re-installed by the GPO.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

1) NO

2) Yes, it’s how it works.

3) Delete the corresponding key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\AppMgmt`